# ggplot 2 scatter plot colors are confused

Tags: r, ggplot2

When you run this code you will see the facet with B has a red point but it clearly should be red. How do you set the colors properly given data frame "d"

Thank you.

```
d = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),y = c(4,5,6), color = c("red","blue","red"), group = c("A","B","A"))
d
ggplot(data= d, aes(x = x, y = y ) ) +geom_point( color = d$color)+
facet_wrap(~group)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `base` plots, `ggplot` doesn't expect you to have a column of color names in your data. It expects you to have a column that defines the variable that you want to color by, and optionally specify the mapping between that vector's values and custom colors (if you don't like the defaults).

In your data, the `color` column seems to be based off of the `group` column. This would be the canonical `ggplot` way to create your plot (notice that the `color` column is not used):

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

Note that you do not need to facet and color by the same column, e.g.,

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ am)
```

The key point is that you are mapping a column to the `color` argument of `aes()` **inside `aes()`**. When facets are involved `ggplot` does potentially complicated splitting of the data behind-the-scenes. This data manipulation is based on the data provided to the data argument and column names provided inside `aes`.

If you specify `data$column` you are passing just a **vector**. You have taken it from your data frame, but `ggplot` doesn't know that - it could have come from anywhere. This will cause mistakes in the subsetting done for the facets. You need to use `aes(color = column)` (note the lack of `data$` - use just the column name inside `aes()`), and `ggplot` will look for a column of that name in the data and know how to correctly filter the data for each facet.

Comment: this feels like a FAQ - it's a very easy mistake to make if you're a bit confused about how ggplot works - but I can't find a dupe ...

Comment: @BenBolker I had the same thought. I was considering asking a new question with the intent of making it a general canonical FAQ, something along the lines of "ggplot scrambles/confuses/wrong colors when I use facets" - I think this one could be made a little more general and much more searchable.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
ggplot(data= d, aes(x = x, y = y ) ) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = color))+
    facet_wrap(~group) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c('red' = 'red','blue' = 'blue'))
```